# Updating XML For A Same Row Multiple Times

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xmlupdate

I have an XML column that needs to be updated multiple time for the same ID.
When I run the query it updates the XML only for the first matching ID.
Here is the query

```
Update  Quote 
Set     [XML].modify('replace value of (/Document/LineItems/LineItem[@ID=sql:column("QLines")]/LineItemStatus/text())[1] with "DELETED"')
From    Quote Qt
    Inner Join @QuoteLines Q on Qt.QuoteID=Q.QtID

@QuoteLines Table
QLines  QtID
30  111645001
40  111645001

Quote Table
QuoteID         XML
111645001   '<Document ID="111645001">'
```

In Quote Table the XML status should be "Deleted" for both lineitem 30 & 40 but it is updating it only for lineitem 30.

I don't have to use Cursors or something like iterations. Thanks

Comment: In future questions, please format your code as code, either by indenting 4 spaces, or highlighting it and clicking the code button (above the question's text area).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232504/how-to-modify-multiple-nodes-using-sql-xquery-in-ms-sql-2005