# Replacing the value of XML attribute

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery

I'm trying to replace the "Visible" attribute value of a Field ID=29 that is duplicated across the xml document.
An example of the xml is found below:

```
<Types>
    <Type ID="4">
        <Fields>
            <Field ID="29" Visible="false"/>
        </Fields>
    </Type>
    <Type ID="5">
        <Fields>
            <Field ID="29" Visible="true"/>
        </Fields>
    </Type>
    <Type ID="6">
        <Fields>
            <Field ID="29" Visible="false"/>
        </Fields>
    </Type>
</Types>
```

I have tried the following but with no success:

```
update SF
set [Static_Form_Properties].modify('replace value of (/Field[@ID=29]/@Visible)[1] with ("true")')
from wf_workflow_step_form SF
```

Any help would be greately appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you cannot do an update of multiple XML node values in a single UPDATE statement, as mentioned here: [How to modify multiple nodes using SQL XQuery in MS SQL 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232504/how-to-modify-multiple-nodes-using-sql-xquery-in-ms-sql-2005)

In your query above I think only the first instance found will be updated.